# Is there a penalty for opposite of cloaking?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, ajax

Let's assume I have 100 different web pages with original and good content.

But I want to publish on these pages same advert content (text video flash pictures)

If I decided to use ajax and jquery for loading that advertorial content after page load, would there be a penalty for that?

I know using hidden div's and hidden text can cause penalties but what if it's the opposite?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really any different then Adsense or any other JavaScript powered ad service serving ads after the page has loaded so you'll be fine.